# How do I use grunt-run to run a npm script?

Tags: gruntjs, jestjs, gulp-jest

How do I run my 'test' npm script using Grunt? It says [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-jest) that I can do it using grunt-run.

**package.json**

```
 .
 .
 "scripts": {
   "test": "jest"
   },
"jest": {
  "preset": "jest-exponent"
 }

.
.
.


"devDependencies": {
  "babel-jest": "^17.0.0",
  "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.9.0",
  "grunt": "^1.0.1",
  "grunt-run": "^0.6.0",
  "jest-exponent": "^0.1.3",
  "jest-react-native": "^17.0.0",
  "react-test-renderer": "^15.3.2"
}
```

**Gulpfile.js - boilerplate code**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
   run: {
     options: {
       // Task-specific options go here.
     },
     your_target: {
       cmd: 'executable',
        args: [
               'arg1',
               'arg2'
        ]
     }
  }
})
```

}

What is the point of Grunt/Gulp if you can just use npm scripts? They require a lot less set up and do the same thing.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. If all you're doing is executing scripts then you don't need grunt or gulp.

Comment: Check this answer, worked for me! https://stackoverflow.com/a/47304117/5346095

Answer (score 0):

not sure if that will helps you, you need install first the task grunt-exec, in my sample i am runing a node server.js

this in my config.

**Gruntfile.js**

```
config.exec = {
         run_server: 'node server.js'
}
grunt.registerTask('serve', ['exec:run_server']);
```

**package.json**

```
 "grunt-exec": "^1.0.1",
```

Comment: But I don't see you map the grunt task with some npm script defined in package.json.