# How to execute npm script using grunt-run?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, gruntjs, jestjs

I have a npm task in my package.json file as follows to execute jest testing:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test-jest": "jest",
    "jest-coverage": "jest --coverage"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
  },
```

I want to execute this task `npm run test-jest` using grunt. I installed grunt-run for the same and added the run task, but how do I invoke this npm task there?

```
    run: {
        options: {
          // Task-specific options go here.
        },
        your_target: {
          cmd: 'node'
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Configure your `Gruntfile.js` similar to the [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-run#overview) shown in the docs.

1. Set the value for the `cmd` to `npm`.
2. Set `run` and `test-jest` in the `args` Array.

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-run');

  grunt.initConfig({
    run: {
      options: {
        // ...
      },
      npm_test_jest: {
        cmd: 'npm',
        args: [
          'run',
          'test-jest',
          '--silent'
        ]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'run:npm_test_jest' ]);

};
```

**Running**

Running `$ grunt` via your CLI using the configuration shown above will invoke the `npm run test-jest` command.

Note: Adding `--silent` (or it's shorthand equivalent `-s`) to the `args` Array simply helps avoids the additional npm log to the console.

---

**EDIT:**

**Cross Platform**

Using the `grunt-run` solution shown above failed on Windows OS when running via `cmd.exe`. The following error was thrown:

> `Error: spawn npm ENOENT Warning: non-zero exit code -4058 Use --force to continue.`

For a cross-platform solution consider installing and utlizing [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) to invoke the `npm run test-jest` instead.

`npm i -D grunt-shell`

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt); // <-- uses `load-grunt-tasks`

  grunt.initConfig({
    shell: {
      npm_test_jest: {
        command: 'npm run test-jest --silent',
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'shell:npm_test_jest' ]);

};
```

**Notes**

1. `grunt-shell` requires [load-grunt-tasks](https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-grunt-tasks) for loading the Task instead of the typical `grunt.loadNpmTasks(...)`, so you'll need to install that too:

`npm i -D load-grunt-tasks`

2. For older version of Windows I had to install an older version of `grunt-shell`, namely version `1.3.0`, so I recommend installing an earlier version.

`npm i -D grunt-shell@1.3.0`

---

**EDIT 2**

**`grunt-run` does seem to work on Windows if you use the `exec` key instead of the `cmd` and `args` keys...**

For cross platform purposes... I found it necessary to specify the command as a single string using the `exec` key as per the documentation that reads:

> If you would like to specify your command as a single string, useful
>   for specifying multiple commands in one task, use the exec: key

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-run');

  grunt.initConfig({
    run: {
      options: {
        // ...
      },
      npm_test_jest: {
        exec: 'npm run test-jest --silent' // <-- use the exec key.
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'run:npm_test_jest' ]);

};
```

Comment: Running the task via CLI threw me this error: Running "run:npm_test_jest" (run) task
>> Error: spawn npm ENOENT
Warning: non-zero exit code -4058 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Comment: Yes, using `grunt-run` I also got the same error when running on Windows - yet it works successfully on Mac. Did you try using [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) instead of `grunt-run` - as explained in the _Cross Platform_ section of my answer? Using `grunt-shell` was successfully for me on both Windows and Mac.

Comment: Thanks Manu - I've actually just found a way to use `grunt-run` cross platform using the `exec` key instead. So If your preference is to use `grunt-run` instead of `grunt-shell` then see my updated answer under the _EDIT 2_ section.

Comment: That works like a champ! Plus I was able to use the shell task independently like grunt shell:npm_test_jest and it worked, but if I registered it with another task and ran that one then it tries to run endlessly with no execution. Switched to grunt-run!

Comment: @RobC - while this is helpful, still not having success with edit2 version. My grunt.js is:  `module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // Activate on subgrunt
    grunt.initConfig({
        run: {
            build: {
                exec: 'npm',
                args: [
                    'run', 'build'
                ]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-run');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['run']);
    grunt.registerTask('build', ['run']);
};`

Comment: @Mark - Have you tried completely omitting the `args` key/value, (as pèr my recommendation in edit2), and placing the `npm run build` command as a value of  the `exec` key. For instance: `grunt.initConfig({ run: { build: { exec: 'npm run build' } } });`

Comment: @RobC - thanks, tried that, but still issue. Problem here is the dev team that spun this up and still uses it are on Macs and I prefer Windows. That said, my initial question [in the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52453809/running-grunt-with-node-in-windows-fails) with the error referencing error 1 and this: `mkdir -p static/build` still exists. Any further recommendations please?

Comment: @Mark - Try running `npm run build` directly in your command-line and if the errors still persist, then it would be indicative that the error has nothing to do with `grunt-run`. It's most probably related to a nodejs script which you are running. In your `app.js` script you definitely need to change what's suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52453809/running-grunt-with-node-in-windows-fails#comment-91850612). Once running `npm run build` directly in your command-line is successful, then utilizing `grunt-run` should be ok.